# LINQ - Align input parameter dynamically

Tags: c#, linq

I have an expression which is created on a class. It is created programmatically based on specific requirements. An example of such expression which is saved in variable `exp` of type `Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>` is -

```
{ p2 => p2.name.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }).Any(p2.salary > 10000) }
```

I am having source data in a variable `empDetails` of type `List<Employee>`. I want to execute the above expression `exp` on `empDetails`.

Comment: what do you want as item and index? Employee and id?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny I need Index.

Comment: I think you need review your expression, 1. you can't use a Boolean expression in `.Any()`, maybe `.Any(_ => p2.salary > 10000)` and ..., Please explain what your expression should do? ;).

Comment: BTW, You can compile your expression like `empDetails.Where(exp.Compile());` ;).

Answer (score 0):

the expression in use is wrong, you get a compile time error if you will try to write it.

i am using a simpler expression for as an example.

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> ext = (p) =>  p.salary > 10000; 

list.Where(ext.Compile());
```

ext.Compile() transforms the Expression> to a Func. then it can be used in any method that take a Func: Where,First, FirstOrDeafult, Single, SingleOrDeafult, Any, All....